# How can I open a specific file from the HTML form?

Tags: php, html

[image]

In the HTML file below, you can see the code for a simple form. After submitting, I would like to open the file marked with '2' in the picture on left. I do not understand why the URL marked with '1' does not open that file. However, if I copy that link (marked with '1') and paste it in the search bar of my browser, it works well.

Comment: File name is `index.php` but you used `index.php/entry` in form action

Comment: Yes, because I use "/entry" as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute URLs must start with a scheme such as `http://` or `https://`.